# Is an achieved model fit of a measurement model (SEM/CFA) "more important" than a minimum level of factor loadings (e.g.: > .4)?

Tags: structural-equation-modeling, confirmatory-factor

I have a SEM model with three factors. One factor is measured with 5 items. Two factors with 35 and 10 respectively.

Since the two factors with the many items did not produce a good model under the CFA of the two-step procedure (first test CFA of the measurement models, then SEM), I reduced the items for both factors to 3 parcels.

The factor with the 5 items met the model fit after a modification (allowing cross-loading between items 1 and 2).

The factor loadings look something like this:

**ITEM1 0.35
ITEM2 0.48
ITEM3 0.81
ITEM4 0.64
ITEM5 0.72**

Some literature suggests that factor loadings should be .4 or higher.

I could certainly achieve such factor loadings by parceling. Moreover, I have read in Bandalos (2002) that parceling even makes the estimates parameters closer to the real values in the population.

What is more important, to include the questionnaire as it is (since the model fit is good) or to achieve higher factor loadings and maybe more accurate parameter estimates?

I would also appreciate a citation of a source if answered.

Thanks!

Ps. The authors are reporting a unidimensionality of the questionnaire.